# Online upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 stuck

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, kubuntu, 14.04

I was trying to upgrade my Lenovo T500 laptop from Kubuntu 12.04 LTS to Kubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Fired up the upgrade process, and finally after downloading a zillion packages the upgrade got going, only to get stuck...

It has been stuck for hours on:

```
 Installing the upgrades->Unpacking subversion
```

Last lines of error messages:

```
GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.32.4/./gobject/gtype.c:2722: You forgot to call g_type_init() at /usr/lib/perl/5.18/DynaLoader.pm line 207.

GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed at /usr/lib/perl/5.18/DynaLoader.pm line 207.
```

I don't care much about subversion anymore, I use git now; I don't care if subversion ends up in a bad state and I have to remove it.

I just want the upgrade to continue, and hopefully complete.

Any idea?

Comment: try uninstalling subversion and restarting installation? (I'm assuming it errored out after that?)

Comment: I am afraid of leaving the system in a really unstable state if I kill the upgrade outright, but yes, that might be the only option.

Comment: I tried installing using an upgrade, but it just died on me, I ended up re-installing. If you have a seperate home partition it should be a piece of cake, just create a live cd/usb before rebooting

Comment: @hamhut1066 Ubuntu preserves the data in /home with a fresh install, it does not matter if /home is on a separate partition or not. This has been the behavior for Ubuntu for 6 + years. "Since Hardy it is possible to reinstall Ubuntu without losing the content of the /home folder (the folder that contains program settings, internet bookmarks, emails and all your documents, music, videos and other user files). **This can be done even if /home is not on a separate partition** " https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

Comment: If you have problems with an upgrade, it is almost always easier and faster to do a fresh install. You should already have your data backed up ;)

Comment: > You should already have your data backed up ;)

Of course, I have two verified backups; one is a tar file of /home and the other one an image of the whole partition.

But back to the question, does anybody know how to kill the current upgrade package step, but let the rest of the dist upgrade continue, to see what happens?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, I normally assume that operating systems break everything, and take necessary precautions regardless. Thank you for enlightening me to this fact though. If this is true, then I recommend a fresh install, it will be faster, and there is a much lower chance of something going wrong in the long run.

Comment: hmm, you could kill the pid, then try again. I haven't had a good look at how it works.

Comment: looking at the script, it seems that it runs apt-get. So you could probably safely kill it and restart the script. it then goes into a sandbox and runs `fetcher` (I haven't looked at this)

Comment: The upgrade also crashed on me (remind to myself: never again do an upgrade from the graphical desktop). I restarted it from a VC with `do-release-upgrade -d`(follow the instruction for the server), followed by `apt-get install -f`, follow by `apt-get dist-upgrade`. It worked at the end.

Comment: OK, it is pretty clear that the 14.04 LTS "upgrade" process is broken at the moment, and a full fresh install is the safest route.

The process that stopped and left my upgrade hanging seems to have been:
[code]
/usr/bin/perl -w /usr/share/debconf/frontend /var/lib/dpkg/info/man-db.postinst triggered /usr/share/man 

I killed it, and the upgrade nominally continued for awhile, only to get stuck again a bit later when setting up tzdata with the same problem ( /usr/lib/perl/5.18/DynaLoader.pm )

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem as well but I figured out a way around it.

After the upgrade has stalled look for the process called "frontend" in the process tree of "python->sudo->trusty->trusty->...->...->frontend" that the upgrade-manager is running under. Once you kill this sub-process the installation process will start again and complete cleanly.

This is related to something involving updating of the man-db. It is not related to subversion, or python, or whatever was being unpacked. That was just the last bit in the logs. The problem is something related to man-db and (probably) perl.

Recommending a fresh install as a first course of action is not exactly helpful. That's what you do when problem solving fails. It isn't a solution.

Comment: This sounds totally legit, the problem for me was that it wouldn't allow me to open a terminal to look for the process and kill it. Not via the menu, not via CTRL ALT T, so I ended up restarting. It's now not booting, so it's going to be another fresh install to a new hd, along with setting everything up yet again. Goddamit, *this* is why it still isn't the year of the desktop...

Comment: If you're ever in that situation again try switching to a text console with Ctrl+Alt+F6. To switch back to the X desktop press Ctrl+Alt+F7.

Comment: @superkuh Thanks you helped me. I did the same thing but on my Xubuntu but the keys were `atl + ctrl + f1` and `alt + ctrl + f3`. I recommend you put this peice of advice in your answer as comments can be deleted at any time.

Comment: Had a similar problem. Same error, upgrade stuck during "preparing python (or something, sorry it's gone and I don't remember)". Killed the process with the name "frontend" in it and the upgrade resumed.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this exact problem doing an upgrade from 12.04 -> 14.04. I was unable to kill the frontend process as described above, because although I could launch an Xterm window, sudo and su segfaulted due to the system being half-upgraded.

However, I recovered from the situation by rebooting, going into recovery mode, and getting it to fix broken packages. This effectively restarted the upgrade process in command line mode and I ended up (eventually) with a usable 14.04 system.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but was stuck at starting mysql.

`ps fax | less` and found frontend. It had a child which was running `start mysql`

In another terminal I ran `sudo stop mysql` which seemed to free up whatever the start was waiting for and the install continued.

I suspect this is generally applicable. Find frontend's lowest child process and kill or unstick that and things will resume.